# I have a core dump of an executable that was NOT built with debug symbols. Can I recover argv contents?

Tags: gdb, coredump

I have a core dump of an executable that was NOT built with debug symbols.

Can I recover argv contents to see what the command line was?

If I run gdb, I can see a backtrace, and I can navigate to the main() frame. Once there, is there a way to recover argv, without knowing its exact address?

I am on x86_x64 (Intel Xeon CPU) running a CEntOS Linux distro/kernel,

One reason I am hopeful is that the core dump seems to show a partial argv.

(The program is postgres, and when I load the core file, gdb prints a message that includes the postgres db-user name, client OP address, and first 10 characters of the query))

Comment: As far as I know, the x86_64 calling convention passes the first few arguments in registers, thus the value of argv is not necessarily saved anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On `x86_64` the arguments are passed in `%rdi`, `%rsi`, etc. registers ([calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)).

Therefore, when you step into the `main` frame, you should be able to:

```
(gdb) p $rdi           # == argc
(gdb) p (char**) $rsi  # == argv

(gdb) set $argv = (char**)$rsi
(gdb) set $i = 0
(gdb) while $argv[$i]
> print $argv[$i++]
> end
```

Unfortunately, GDB will not normally restore `$rdi` and `$rsi` when you switch frames. So this example doesn't work:

```
cat t.c

#include <stdlib.h>

int bar() { abort(); }
int foo() { return bar(); }
int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}

gcc t.c && ./a.out
Aborted (core dumped)

gdb -q ./a.out core
Core was generated by `./a.out'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fdc8284aa75 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fdc8284aa75 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007fdc8284e5c0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x000000000040052d in bar ()
#3  0x000000000040053b in foo ()
#4  0x000000000040054b in main ()
(gdb) fr 4
#4  0x000000000040054b in main ()
(gdb) p $rdi
$1 = 5524    ### clearly not the right value
```

So you'll have to work some more ...

What you *can* do is use the knowledge of how Linux stack is set up at [process startup](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html), combined with the fact that GDB *will* restore stack pointer:

```
(gdb) set backtrace past-main
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a8da75 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff7a915c0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x000000000040052d in bar ()
#3  0x000000000040053b in foo ()
#4  0x0000000000400556 in main ()
#5  0x00007ffff7a78c4d in __libc_start_main (main=<optimized out>, argc=<optimized out>, ubp_av=<optimized out>, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdad8) at libc-start.c:226
#6  0x0000000000400469 in _start ()

(gdb) frame 6
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x0000000000400440 <+0>: xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x0000000000400442 <+2>: mov    %rdx,%r9
   0x0000000000400445 <+5>: pop    %rsi
   0x0000000000400446 <+6>: mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x0000000000400449 <+9>: and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
   0x000000000040044d <+13>:    push   %rax
   0x000000000040044e <+14>:    push   %rsp
   0x000000000040044f <+15>:    mov    $0x400560,%r8
   0x0000000000400456 <+22>:    mov    $0x400570,%rcx
   0x000000000040045d <+29>:    mov    $0x40053d,%rdi
   0x0000000000400464 <+36>:    callq  0x400428 <__libc_start_main@plt>
=> 0x0000000000400469 <+41>:    hlt    
   0x000000000040046a <+42>:    nop
   0x000000000040046b <+43>:    nop
End of assembler dump.
```

So now we expect the original `%rsp` to be `$rsp+8` (one POP, two PUSHes), but it could be at `$rsp+16` due to alignment that was done at instruction `0x0000000000400449`

Let's see what's there ...

```
(gdb) x/8gx $rsp+8
0x7fffbe5d5e98: 0x000000000000001c  0x0000000000000004
0x7fffbe5d5ea8: 0x00007fffbe5d6eb8  0x00007fffbe5d6ec0
0x7fffbe5d5eb8: 0x00007fffbe5d6ec4  0x00007fffbe5d6ec8
0x7fffbe5d5ec8: 0x0000000000000000  0x00007fffbe5d6ecf
```

That looks promising: 4 (suspected argc), followed by 4 non-NULL pointers, followed by NULL.

Let's see if that pans out:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffbe5d6eb8
0x7fffbe5d6eb8:  "./a.out"
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffbe5d6ec0
0x7fffbe5d6ec0:  "foo"
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffbe5d6ec4
0x7fffbe5d6ec4:  "bar"
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffbe5d6ec8
0x7fffbe5d6ec8:  "bazzzz"
```

Indeed, that's how I invoked the binary. As a final sanity check, does `0x00007fffbe5d6ecf` look like part of the enovironment?

```
(gdb) x/s 0x00007fffbe5d6f3f
0x7fffbe5d6f3f:  "SSH_AGENT_PID=2874"
```

Yep, that's the beginning (or the end) of the environment.

So there you have it.

Final notes: if GDB didn't print `<optimized out>` so much, we could have recovered `argc` and `argv` from frame #5. There is work on both GDB and GCC sides to make GDB print much less of "optimized out" ...

Also, when loading the core, my GDB prints:

```
Core was generated by `./a.out foo bar bazzzz'.
```

negating the need for this whole exercise. However, that only works for short command lines, while the solution above will work for any command line.

Comment: Thanks for the starting info, and it's nice to know that your idea works if the program is launched under gdb, but I don't know where to go next...