# gdb debugging of core.# file - getting the full command which caused the crash

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I have some complicated problem (by complicated I mean that I couldn't find a solution within a few hours of researching) and the problem is:

I submitted large amount of scripts to run (on an SGE cluster), some of those scripts generated core.# files (core dump files). I figured I could open those files with gdb, now when I simply open the core.# file I see this:
(the last few lines of the gdb output)

```
Core was generated by `/tools/graphmap/bin/Linux-x64/graphmap align --overlappe'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000000004a554b in ?? ()
"/4thExp/core.82912" is a core file.
Please specify an executable to debug.
```

Now to my question - I need to find what was the arguments to the program that caused the crash.
The output mentioned above shows only the beginning of the command that caused the crash: "Core was generated by `/groups/nshomron/artemd/tools/graphmap/bin/Linux-x64/graphmap align --overlappe'."

If I could see the rest of the command I would solve my problem, but after hours of searching online and checking gdb manual I couldn't find anything useful. I tried loading gdb with the program that caused the crash "gdb ..../graphmap core.#" but still I got only the beginning of the faulty command and couldn't get anything else.

Any help suggestion would be very appreciated.

**Update:** As the user @ks1322 suggested - I looked closely at the threads.
First I executed "info threads" and got the output:

```
(gdb) info threads
  24 Thread 0x2b29409bd700 (LWP 82927)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  23 Thread 0x2b29401b9700 (LWP 82923)  0x00000031d00f820e in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
* 22 Thread 0x2b29403ba700 (LWP 82924)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  21 Thread 0x2b29413c2700 (LWP 82932)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  20 Thread 0x2b293fbb6700 (LWP 82920)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  19 Thread 0x2b293fdb7700 (LWP 82921)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  18 Thread 0x2b2940bbe700 (LWP 82928)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  17 Thread 0x2b293f3b2700 (LWP 82916)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  16 Thread 0x2b29411c1700 (LWP 82931)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  15 Thread 0x2b2940dbf700 (LWP 82929)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  14 Thread 0x2b29419c5700 (LWP 82935)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  13 Thread 0x2b293efb0700 (LWP 82914)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  12 Thread 0x2b293f7b4700 (LWP 82918)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  11 Thread 0x2b29407bc700 (LWP 82926)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  10 Thread 0x2b293f9b5700 (LWP 82919)  0x00000031d00f820e in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  9 Thread 0x2b29415c3700 (LWP 82933)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  8 Thread 0x2b29405bb700 (LWP 82925)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  7 Thread 0x2b292ea08be0 (LWP 82912)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  6 Thread 0x2b293ffb8700 (LWP 82922)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  5 Thread 0x2b293edaf700 (LWP 82913)  0x00000031d0045063 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  4 Thread 0x2b2940fc0700 (LWP 82930)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  3 Thread 0x2b293f1b1700 (LWP 82915)  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  2 Thread 0x2b29417c4700 (LWP 82934)  0x0000000000412bd6 in obtainAlignment(unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, int, int, int, unsigned char**, int*) ()
  1 Thread 0x2b293f5b3700 (LWP 82917)  0x00000000004a554b in GraphMap::ProcessKmerCacheFriendly_(signed char*, long, ScoreRegistry*, MappingData*, Index*, SingleSequence const*, ProgramParameters const*) ()
```

It didn't tell me very much so I continued to look for a "main thread". I switched to each thread, one by one, and executed "info stack". The only thread containing something relevant was thread 7. the info stack output:

```
(gdb) thread 7
[Switching to thread 7 (Thread 0x2b292ea08be0 (LWP 82912))]#0  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) info stack
#0  0x00000031d00ac6aa in times () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000031d009bcba in clock () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000000004ccaed in GraphMap::RegionSelectionNoCopy_(long, MappingData*, std::vector<Index*, std::allocator<Index*> >, SingleSequence const*, ProgramParameters const*) ()
#3  0x00000000004c3544 in GraphMap::ProcessRead(MappingData*, std::vector<Index*, std::allocator<Index*> >, SingleSequence const*, ProgramParameters const*, EValueParams const*) ()
#4  0x00000000004adf43 in GraphMap::ProcessSequenceFileInParallel ()
#5  0x00002b292e7f096f in GOMP_parallel () from /share/apps/gcc/gcc530/lib64/libgomp.so.1
#6  0x00000000004b0b08 in GraphMap::ProcessSequenceFileInParallel(ProgramParameters*, SequenceFile*, long*, _IO_FILE*, long*, long*) ()
#7  0x00000000004b1796 in GraphMap::ProcessReadsFromSingleFile(ProgramParameters&, _IO_FILE*) ()
#8  0x00000000004b281e in GraphMap::Run(ProgramParameters&) ()
#9  0x00000000005087fe in main ()
```

But I got stuck again from here (short reminder: my goal is to find the full command that crushed the execution, the beginning of which is displayed on the first page of gdb like this:

> Core was generated by `/tools/graphmap/bin/Linux-x64/graphmap align
>   --overlappe'.

Any help from here would be very appreciated.

**Final Update, problem solved**: I followed @ks1322 advice and went to this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9049297/72178) and then I repeated what was described in the first answer and was able to get the arguments.

(short overview of what I understood with my limited knowledge of working with gdb: First you should check what threads were running the task, you can do it with "info threads" then you need to check which thread has "main" in it's stack, I did it by switching threads one by one with "thread #" and printing the stack with "info stack" until I found the thread that had main in it. in my case it was shown like this in the "info stack" #9  0x00000000005087fe in main ()". Then according to the instructions in the linked thread, I executed "set backtrace past-main" then "bt" and then changed frame to the frame containing "in _start ()" with the command "frame #". Almost done, now I ran the command "x/8gx $rsp+8" with showed few four lines with 2 addressees in each line. In my case the second line looked like this "0x7ffe38f872d8: 0x00007ffe38f88c35      0x00007ffe38f88c73" **and now if everything was right this address can contain one of the arguments of the command that caused the crush**, you can check it with "x/s" command like so: "x/s 0x00007ffe38f88c35" and it prints the argument. Important note: I had a lot of arguments so I needed to go to later addressees that did not show in the "x/8gx $rsp+8" command, I noticed that the addresses are incremented by constant value (3 in hex) so I kept manually in a calculator adding "3" to the address and checking the address with x/s until I got to my wanted argument)

Very messy solution and I hope someone could find an easier solution but that is all I could find.

Big thanks to [@ks1322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72178/ks1322) who cleared up things for me and guided me to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load core dump with matching binary (the one for which core dump was generated) and print `argv` values in the frame where `main` function resides.

Something like this:

```
gdb /tools/graphmap/bin/Linux-x64/graphmap /4thExp/core.82912
```

Then go up in stack trace to initial frame where `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` resides. Now you can print the number of arguments and their values from gdb prompt.

Update:
It appears that your binary is multithreaded and crash happened in some auxiliary thread. You should therefore find `main` thread and switch to it. Here is an example of how to do it for Firefox with many threads:

```
(gdb) t a a bt -1

Thread 59 (Thread 0x7f691deff700 (LWP 25924)):
#12 0x00007f69dce93f6f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:105
..........
..........
many threads are listed here
..........
..........
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f69de01a740 (LWP 4143)):
#17 0x000056374cb38817 in main ()
(gdb) t 1
[Switching to thread 1 (Thread 0x7f69de01a740 (LWP 4143))]
#0  0x00007f69dce8800d in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  T_PSEUDO (SYSCALL_SYMBOL, SYSCALL_NAME, SYSCALL_NARGS)
```

Now gdb is switched to `main` thread (Thread 1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried loading it with the matching binary. But I'm not sure how to go up the stack to this place you suggested.I'm not sure if it's relevant but when I run "info stack" I get something like this: "#0  0x00000000004a554b in GraphMap::ProcessKmerCacheFri....
#1  0x00000000004a59ac in GraphMap::GraphMa...
#2  0x00000000004c4d0e in GraphMap::ProcessR....
#3  0x00000000004adf43 in GraphMap::Proce...
#4  0x00002b292e7f401e in gomp_thr...
#5  0x00000031d0807aa1 in start_thr...
#6  0x00000031d00e8aad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6" I have replaced long lines with dots

Comment: Looks like it crashed in some thread, other than `main`. You should find `main` thread and switch to it. Look at the output of `thread apply all bt` and find there the thread with `main` function.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, hope you still can help me with this issue. I'm updating the original post to include the instructions you gave me and the output, though my question is still unanswered unfortunately. Thanks for the help anyway.